# Escaping variables for a function call?

Tags: javascript

In a function, i am building a string. The string is some content for a popup (google maprs info window).
The code looks like this;

```
var windowcontent = "<strong>Something</strong><br/>" + somethingVar + "<br/><br/>";
windowcontent += "<a href='javascript:goto('\"+var1+\"','\"+var2+\"');'>Goto</a>";
```

The problem is the link and the variables i want to include in the function call.
Whatever i try, i cant seem to get it to work. I know it is something with escaping the correct way, but i have not found the correct way yet, it seems.

How should the string, with the link in it, look?

Comment: Don't escape the quote in your second line.

Answer (score 2):

Second line should be

```
windowcontent += "<a href='javascript:goto(\'" + var1 +"\',\'"+ var2 + "\');'>Goto</a>";
```

Basically you need to escape the single quote rather than double quote.

Updated code after discussion, [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/f2gvj10u/2/)

```
var var1 =  encodeURI("(56.02, 9.27)") ;
var var2 =  encodeURI("(56.02, 9.27)") ;

window.addEventListener("load", function()
{
    document.body.innerHTML += '<a  data-var1="' + var1 + '" data-var2="' + var2 + '" href="#" onclick="goto(this)"> Goto </a>';
    console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
}, false);

function goto (thisObj) 
{ 
   console.log(thisObj);
   var var1 = thisObj.getAttribute( "data-var1" );
   var var2 = thisObj.getAttribute( "data-var2" );
    console.log(var1 + ' - ' + var2); 
}
```

Comment: I now have this;
windowcontent += "<a href='javascript:goto(\'" + var1 + "\',\'" + var2 + "\');'>Go</a>";

But i get this error, when i click the link: SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script.

My values for info:
var1 = "(56.02, 9.27)"
var2 = "A long var with numbers 35, and commas etc.,"

Comment: @brother can you show what your goto method look like?

Comment: @gurvinder372 sure thing, its pretty simple: function goto(myvar1, myvar2) {
    console.log(myvar1 + ' - ' + myvar2);
}

Comment: @brother thanks, it is simple indeed. Can you share a fiddle to demonstrate how you are creating the dom through string?

Comment: @brother made this fiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/f2gvj10u/ Let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105649/discussion-between-brother-and-gurvinder372).